# How to use java class in jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have tried running java class in jmeter.
I have placed java code in BSF preprocessor.
But the following error occurred:

```
ERROR - org.apache.bsf.BSFManager: Exception : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.bsf.engines.java.JavaEngine
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190
```

I have tried this [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bsf/index.html) for including jar file.
But i dont know which jar file i need to include.

Can some one tell me which jar file include for running java class in jmeter?

Comment: you are using maven? If not are just one jar into the BSF [zip file](http://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/apache//commons/bsf/binaries/bsf-bin-2.4.0.zip)

Comment: Thanks preis.I did not use maven.I have copied this jar into apache-jmeter/lib folder.but no luck.Again same error.

Comment: Can you show you code and configuration of BSFSampler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use Beanshell instead of Java.

There seems to be a packaging issue in BSF, see

- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jakarta-bsf-user/200810.mbox/%3C48F748CC.3070808@wu-wien.ac.at%3E

> In the meantime, you can get a binary distribution with all BSF engines
>   for BSF 2.4 (as well as a slightly advanced version of BSF 2.4) from
>   http://wi.wu-wien.ac.at/rgf/rexx/bsf4rexx/current/BSF4Rexx_install.zip.
>   After unpacking that zip-archive, you will find a jar-file named
>   "bsf-v244-20080704.jar". Just replace the official BSF 2.4 with that
>   version (which contains all official engines as well as "BSF_Log" and
>   "BSF_LogFactory").

The mentionned jar also has some issues.

Anyway for performance and up to date code, it is better to use JSR223 Sampler + Groovy + fill in Compilation Cache Key

Answer (score 1):

Which versoin of jmeter are you using? With 2.9 jsr 223 pre-processor using java language is working fine for me. I think the jsr223-* elements are superseding beanchell-* and BSF-* elements so you can give it a try.

java and beanshell btw are claimed slow if you have it executed a lot. You can use groovy and JSR223 preprocesor. You can see about caching the compiled code in the [JSR223 sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) docs.

Beanshell and groovy are mostly java code compatible so you can use java code with them but not entirely. Anything more complicated in pure java can fail to compile in groovy and/or beanshell.

If you use pure java, then it makes sense to use the [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler if you can instead of a pre-processor. If technically hard to achieve, the fastest option seems to use groovy with jsr223 pre-processor and caching the compiled code.

Hope this helps.